# How to disable Exoplayer DefaultTimeBar

Tags: android, video-streaming, exoplayer

I need a video player where when the user watches a video for the first time, the user is not allowed to speed up the video with the timer bar, but when the video has been watched to completion, then the user can repeat the video and the seek feature with the timer bar can be used.

I use exoplayer, is it possible to programmatically disable seek / user interaction with the timer bar ?

Answer (score 0):

Exoplayer provides [this API](https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/ui/DefaultTimeBar.html#setEnabled-boolean-), below are its source codes:

```
  @Override
  public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    super.setEnabled(enabled);
    updateScrubberState();
    if (scrubbing && !enabled) {
      stopScrubbing(true);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

For disabling **Timebar** of *exoplayer* you may follow below steps :

1.First we need to add

```
app:controller_layout_id="@layout/layout_exoplayer_control_views"
```

for our PlayerView in xml file.

2.Second we need to add layout_exoplayer_control_views in layout folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tool="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#99000000"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:paddingTop="12dp"
    android:paddingBottom="12dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrier_left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierDirection="left"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="exo_pause,exo_play" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/exo_rew"
        style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Rewind"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_rewind"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:padding="@dimen/dp_10"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/exo_play"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/barrier_left"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/exo_play"
        app:tint="@color/yellow" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/exo_ffwd"
        style="@style/ExoMediaButton.FastForward"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_fast_forward"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:padding="@dimen/dp_10"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/exo_play"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/barrier_right"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/exo_play"
        app:tint="@color/yellow" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrier_right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierDirection="right"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="exo_pause,exo_play" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/exo_play"
        style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Play"
        android:layout_width="56dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_new_play"
        android:padding="@dimen/dp_10"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:tint="@color/yellow" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/exo_pause"
        style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Pause"
        android:layout_width="56dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_pause"
        android:padding="@dimen/dp_10"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:tint="@color/yellow" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/videoTimeContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="70dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@id/exo_position"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:minWidth="50dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/exo_progress"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/exo_progress"
            tool:text="dssdd" />

        <your.package.name.CustomTimeBar
            android:id="@+id/exo_progress"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:buffered_color="@color/gray1"
            app:played_color="@color/yellow"
            app:scrubber_color="@color/green_dark"
            app:unplayed_color="@color/gray_2"
            app:scrubber_enabled_size="0dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@id/exo_duration"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:minWidth="50dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/exo_progress"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/exo_progress"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/exo_progress"
            tool:text="dssdd" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/exo_go_live"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/round_solid_yellow"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:minWidth="50dp"
            android:minHeight="25dp"
            android:minEms="4"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingTop="6dp"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:paddingBottom="6dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/exo_progress"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/exo_progress"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/exo_progress"
            tool:text="dssdd" />

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

3.At the end you need to put below file with your java file(**CustomTimeBar**) :

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.DefaultTimeBar;

public class CustomTimeBar extends DefaultTimeBar {
    public CustomTimeBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    // Override onTouchEvent to intercept scrubbing touch events and ignore them.
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent event) {
        // If you want to disable scrubbing on any touch event (including seek),
        // you can just return true here, and the touch event will be consumed.
        // Otherwise, you can check the event action to selectively disable scrubbing.
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Note : Please replace your.package.name.CustomTimeBar  with your project package.**